# React-Select: How to display empty redux-form <Field /> when user selects "other" option from dropdown?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, react-select

I am using `react-select` component and currently working on displaying a `redux-form` `<Field />` component on selecting the "other" option from the drop down (select box list). I tried with `onChange` method but it is not working.

Below is my `SelectInput.js`

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'react-select/dist/react-select.css';

export default (props) => (
    <Select
        {...props}
        value={props.input.value}
        onChange={(value) => props.input.onChange(value) }
        onBlur={() => props.input.onBlur(props.input.value) }
        options = {props.options} />
);
```

This one is my main page `SampleSelect.js`

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import SelectInput from './SelectInput';


class SampleSelect extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    }

    handleChange(event) //I have written this function to display an empty field on selecting "Other" option from dropdown. 
    {
        if (event.target.value == "THR") {
            this.setState({ selected: true })
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ selected: false })
        }
    }

    render() {

        const options = [{ value: 'THR', label: 'Other' }];
        const content = this.state.selected ? <Field name ="Other" id="otherBox" component ="input" /> : null;

        return (

            <div>
                Select Options: <Field name="selectField" component={SelectInput} onChange={this.handleChange} options={options} />  //Tried this but not working.
                <div>
                    {content}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default SampleSelect;
```

Please guide me how to trigger `onChange` method and display an `<Field />` on selecting "other" option from `react-select` box.

*One thing to note:* I can able to submit the value from wrapped `react-select` box to form, but want to implement displaying of text field on selection of "Other" option. Please guide.

Thanks,
shash

Answer (score 0):

You need to import both `Field` and `reduxForm` for them to work.

```
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
```

Then you need to wrap your form in a `reduxForm` function with options argument.

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'SampleSelect'  // a unique identifier for this form
})(SampleSelect)
```

Only then can you pass on custom fields. See this [example from the docs](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/examples/simple/).

Finally, make sure to set your initial state in the constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.state = { selected: false };
}
```